# I have Visual Studio 2013 running on my pc, I want to install Visual Basic 6 side by side. Is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I want to install Visual Studio as I have also running Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition on the same PC.

I need help figuring out if there are any problems with the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, and no, you don't have to do anything special; the two IDEs are entirely separate, you just install each of them. Of course, the Visual Basic 6 IDE has been end-of-lifed for ***years*** now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the question is not silly. Installing VB6 used to break previously installed versions of Visual Studio and usually required them to be reinstalled (and depending on the direction of the wind might require some registry hacking as well). Since VS2010 you can safely install VB6 after Visual Studio.

Comment: tHAT MEANS U SAID I HAV TO INSTALL FIRST VISUAL STUDIO6 THEN VISUAL STUDIO 2013??

Comment: With pre-Visual Studio 2010 that is what you had to do. From 2010 onwards installing VS6 doesn't seem to break anything.